# Aws amplify facebook login app - broken url detected

Tags: facebook, aws-amplify, amazon-cognito-facebook

Simple question really.
How do I make my facebook app live.

Steps taken...
I made a very basic project by running:

- create-react-app;
- amplify init;

Then I created a facebook app in facebook for developers.

Using the app id and app secret from that app I ran:

- amplify add auth
- amplify push

At which point my amplify project was created in AWS.
I took the user pool domain and added it to the facebook app:
App domains: [Userpool Domain]
Site url: https://[Userpool Domain]/oauth2/idpresponse

At this point I can use aws amplify in my react project to login using facebook, so it must be set up correctly.

But I can't set my facebook app to live, since it complains about a broken url detected.
And using the sharing debugger I see the https:///oauth2/idpresponse  url returns a response code 400.

Can anyone please tell me.
How do I fix this??

This is the error thrown by facebook:
[image]

Comment: https:///oauth2/idpresponse is not a valid URL. It is missing a domain name.

Comment: It was just a mistake with the initial text I wrote <User Domain> escaped to nothing.

Anyways the url does have a domain name and as I said the way I've configured the facebook app does work, like I can log in to it via amplify auth.

I just can't set the facebook app from development to live.

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot of the actual error message?

Comment: I've updated the my initial question, it now includes a snippet of the Facebook error thrown.

Comment: in my opinion some new update for facebook apps is causing this error, I have several other apps working correctly and now I am trying to create one and I get the same error message

Comment: @user1479897 I could avoid the error, making fun of it this way: the error is in the site url, according to the documentation we must add to our hosted ui endpoint "/oauth2/idpresponse" this causes the error, so what I did was not add "/oauth2/ idpresonse" then put the app in live and once in live add "/oauth2/idpresponse". Until now I will prove that the rest works correctly !!

Comment: Thanks @Brian that also worked for me.

Comment: I got the same error and your way worked. thank @Brian